# how can I make this thing responsive

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid

what I'm trying is to make this page responsive between 640px and 1280px. my first two media-quarries are functioning properly but the problem is my third one. I've already tried several options but nothing is working out. Here is the problem when I reach 829px the header, the nav, the aside and the footer works no matter the width of the screen but the section part doesn't working no matter what.

```
  @media (max-width: 1260px) {  
     #container {  
     display: grid;
     grid-template-areas: 
       "header header header"
       "nav section section"
       "nav aside aside"
       "footer footer footer";
      grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 5px;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 10px;   
   }
    ul li {
    display: block-inline; 
   }
  }
  @media (max-width: 1223px) {
  #container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header header header"
  "nav nav nav"
  "section section section"
  "aside aside aside"
  "footer footer footer";
   grid-template-rows: 1fr;
   grid-template-columns: 13% 1fr 18%;
   grid-gap: 5px;
   height: 100vh;
   margin: 10px;  
  }
 ul li {
  text-align: center; 
  }
 }

  @media (max-width: 829px) {
  #container #products {
   display: grid; 
  grid-template-areas:
   "header"
  "nav"
  "section"
  "section"
  "aside"
  "footer";

   }
 }
```

Comment: your grid is expecting 3 columns, so you need to give it 3 words per row in that 3rd media query. but if you want just the header over just the nav over just the section over just the aside over just the footer, then your 2nd media query should be doing that already

Comment: also, are you trying to make #products a grid container? if so you need to have it set up in css the way you did #container

Comment: yea I know..its doing that already apart from the section part which is not responding to anything.

Comment: No... just the container.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a different element on third `@media`, let me show you:

```
@media (max-width: 1223px) {
  #container { ... }
 }

 @media (max-width: 829px) {
  #container #products { ... } // Do you want to change #container or #products??
```